# STRFTIME - not matching with Test.py testcase - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-3.6

I have course test cases that need to be submitted. I have a test.py file is provided with the question for checking my jupyter notebook. Its read only and I am not allowed to edit it.

test.py

---

```
import re
from hashlib import md5
import nbformat
import pickle
def read_ipynb_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as file:
        out = str(nbformat.read(file_path, as_version=4))
    return out
path = 'question/EDA_question.ipynb'
out = read_ipynb_file(path)
max_p_range_day =  re.findall(r'max_p_range_day\s*=\s*\'\d*[-,]?\d*[-,]?\d*\'', out)[0].replace(' ', '').replace(' ', '').replace("'", "")
```

---

I am getting below error, while running the test script:-

---

test.py:23:

```
max_p_range_day =  re.findall(r'max_p_range_day\s*=\s*\'\d*[-,]?\d*[-,]?\d*\'', out)[0].replace(' ', '').replace("'", "")
```

E   IndexError: list index out of range    ***

The code I have written as below:-

```
data["Diffpres"]= data["Maximum pressure "] - data["Minimum pressure "]
filt2 = data["Diffpres"]==data["Diffpres"].max()
date2 =data.loc[filt2]['Date1']
max_p_range_day = date2.dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").values[0]
```

---

The question is as follows for the above code :-

Out of all available records which day has the highest difference between maximum_pressure and minimum_pressure

- assign the date in string format as 'yyyy-mm-dd'. Make sure you enclose it with single quote

Not sure what I am doing incorrect here. I tried changing strftime but not lucky enough. Need your expertise advise...

```
Day Average temperature (°F)    Average humidity (%)    Average dewpoint (°F)   Average barometer (in)  Average windspeed (mph) Average gustspeed (mph) Average direction (°deg)    Rainfall for month (in) Rainfall for year (in)  Maximum rain per minute Maximum temperature (°F)    Minimum temperature (°F)    Maximum humidity (%)    Minimum humidity (%)    Maximum pressure    Minimum pressure    Maximum windspeed (mph) Maximum gust speed (mph)    Maximum heat index (°F)
0   1/01/2009   37.8    35  12.7    29.7    26.4    36.8    274 0.0 0.0 0.0 40.1    34.5    44  27  29.762  29.596  41.4    59.0    40.1
1   2
```

Error Message *********

```
___________________________________________________ ERROR collecting test.py ____________________________________________________
test.py:23: in <module>
    max_p_range_day =  re.findall(r'max_p_range_day\s*=\s*\'\d*[-,]?\d*[-,]?\d*\'', out)[0].replace(' ', '').replace("'", "")
E   IndexError: list index out of range
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
==================================================== 1 error in 0.24 seconds ===============
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would it possible to provide some more of the error message, and maybe some more of the relevant code? Also, could you include some code to construct an example dataframe? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for details.

Comment: I have added dataframe

Answer (score 1):

`Pandas` is the perfect tool for this. Using a demo dataframe that has different
column names, the following code shows how it could be done:

```
import pandas as pd

sample = {'day': ['1/01/2009', '1/02/2009', '1/03/2009'],
      'pmin': [7, 5, 4],
      'pmax': [8, 6.5, 6.5]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sample)
# Calculate pressure difference between min and max for each row
df['pdiff'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.pmax-x.pmin, axis=1)
# Convert string format date into Timestamp
df['date'] = df.day.apply(pd.Timestamp)
print(df)
#          day  pmin  pmax  dmax       date
# 0  1/01/2009     7   8.0   1.0 2009-01-01
# 1  1/02/2009     5   6.5   1.5 2009-01-02
# 2  1/03/2009     4   6.5   2.5 2009-01-03

# Get index of maximum pressure difference, convert date of row into string
print(df.loc[df.pdiff.idxmax()].date.isoformat())
# '2009-01-03T00:00:00'
print("max_p_range_day = '23-03-2018'")
```

Comment: Thanks @VirtualScooter..I am getting the right value from my code as max_p_range_day = '23-03-2018' and this is the correct answer. So logic of getting correct date is working. But Test.py is throwing an error for the above value. The line of code where it throws value  and saying "Index Out of error" is :-    **** test.py:23: in <module>
    max_p_range_day =  re.findall(r'max_p_range_day\s*=\s*\'\d*[-,]?\d*[-,]?\d*\'', out)[0].replace(' ', '').replace("'", "")
E   IndexError: list index out of range******  Can you see the above code and advise what it expects. I read this s- space d-value

Comment: @MVKXXX can you please elaborate "After rectifying the issue strftime() worked". Thanks

Comment: @PKM, if this is the correct answer, then please accept it as such in SO. Also, with respect to the `IndexError`, I've updated the answer with a line that is apparently required by the answer checker.

Comment: I can't edit test.py ..hence I need to modify my answer to match below code's expectation:                                                                                           max_p_range_day = re.findall(r'max_p_range_day\s*=\s*\'\d*[-,]?\d*[-,]?\d*\'', out)[0].replace(' ', '').replace("'", "")

Comment: @PKM, I understand you can't edit `test.py`. But you can edit your notebook script that you are uploading right? What you have quoted under "this is what I have written so far"? The `test.py` script is inspecting output (`out`), to see if there is an output line that says `max_p_range_day = ...`.

Comment: Please check       
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66509614/strftime-not-matching-with-test-py-testcase-indexerror-list-index-out-of-ra

Comment: @PKM, I do not understand. Can you please explain why you can't make the change that I suggested in my last comment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229638/discussion-between-p-k-m-and-virtualscooter).